# Use version qualifier replacement in buckminster

Tags: eclipse, build, buckminster

In my cspex I have action that creates product

```
<public name="create.product" actor="ant">
        <actorProperties>
            <property key="buildFile" value="build/product.ant" />
            <property key="targets" value="create.product" />
        </actorProperties>
        <properties>
            <property key="profile" value="iitProfile" />
            <property key="iu" value="iit.product" />
        </properties>
        <prerequisites alias="repository">
            <attribute name="site.p2" />
        </prerequisites>
        <products alias="destination" base="${buckminster.output}">
            <path path="product.${target.ws}.${target.os}.${target.arch}/" />
        </products>
    </public>
```

When the final product is being build, folder created looks like this product.${target.ws}.${target.os}.${target.arch}. How can I append qualifier replacement that I set via qualifier.replacement property? I thought I could do something like product.${target.ws}.${target.os}.${target.arch}_{qualifier.replacement} where qualifier.replacement is the property that was set during execution of buckminster.versionQualifier.

I know when I execute action site.p2.zip qualifier replacement is being appended to the name of the file, so how can I use this in my other actions? Do I have execute buckminster.versionQualifier task myself?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Opened enhancement about this on eclipse bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321753